# what is preventing activating MS Office 365 on Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, software-activation

This is an extremely technical question.

I'm installing and activating Microsoft 365 (was 'Office') on my Mac running 14.1.2. I signed up for a trial subscription, and the software installation goes fine. When I try to activate any 365 app, it wants me to log in, which I do. I get the screen "this email is used by more than one account", but I can get past that by selecting 'For personal use' option. Then I get the screen "No license found".

- I've visited and tried about 10 different support pages about troubleshooting Activation, including pages about troubleshooting Activation on a Mac. (Many of those pages are clearly outdated as of OS14.)
- I've downloaded and run the [license erasure software](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-remove-office-license-files-on-a-mac-b032c0f6-a431-4dad-83a9-6b727c03b193), and run
  [this AppleScript](https://github.com/JamesCaudill/ActivationTroubleShooter) pointed to by the [Can't Activate on a Mac
  page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-to-try-if-you-can-t-install-or-activate-office-for-mac-5efba2b4-b1e6-4e5f-bf3c-6ab945d03dea).
- I've run all the more obscure instructions to delete one's
  365 licensing information from your keychain (I searched for
  'microsoft', 'office', and 'ms' looking for things to delete; I think I got it all).
- I've gotten rid of plists and preference files for Office. I've tried [these instructions from Hong Kong](https://its.hku.hk/kb/cannot-activate-office-365-on-my-mac/).
- I've reinstalled Office twice.
- I've restarted the Mac twice.
- I've visited Office.com/signin and confirmed it thinks I have Office 365 on this account.
- I've tried [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2489405-cant-activate-office-on-mac): "defaults write com.microsoft.Word
  ResetOneAuthCreds -bool YES".
- And this (and its parent): "chmod 755
  ./PrivilegedHelperTools".
- And this: "Click Go>Go to folder>go to
  Library>Group containers>delete the folder UBF8T346G9.Office" (and
  deleted a few more folders besides).
- I've tried creating an additional shared account under this subscription. I still get the same behavior trying to activate using that new shared account.

(Does the length of this list suggest a fundamental problem to anyone
else…? )

The most useful advice so far was in a post I can't find any more, which suggested authenticating that MS account using another account on my computer. So I tried that, and it authenticated fine in that account. (!) So this suggests there is no problem on the MS server end.  Unlike the original post that talked about that scenario, though, this activation in my second computer account didn't affect my ability to use the system in the primary computer account (after all the usual logging off and on and restarting), even though the Office installation is in the system Applications folder.

Since it is no longer possible to have any sort of dialog with an expert from Microsoft (the published phone number directs you back to web support, and the Technical Support link is just for companies/MS sysadmins, and there is no chat option I could find anywhere), StackExchange is my only hope. [Update: On day 2 the links actually did end up at human destinations. Maybe it was a holiday? So maybe there is hope at MS, see rest of update below.]

Can anyone provide additional or clearer details about exactly what I could try to enable my 365 account?  (Thank you for listening…)

**Day 2 Update**

I spent over 2 hours today with Microsoft support, first from the store and then from Office Support team(?). I got cut off twice and ignored for 20 minutes the third time, and the main result was that I confirmed the problem still occurs after logging out of my account from Word or Excel. (And it still works fine on my other user account on the computer.).

- I tried deleting the MS caches in ~/Library/Caches but this had no impact. Will try again with support.

**Week 2 Update**

Still without a solution, I did a clean reinstall of the Mac OS, created a new account, and confirmed that I could use Office on my new account. I then tried on another new account, with the only difference being that I restored my keychain to the one from the previous computer, again deleting anything I could find that related to Office. (Bit of a long list, really.) The keychain appeared to be working fine, but now I couldn't log into Office again (same issue as above).

Comment: Could not agree more, but then, that's what this site is for, complex issues. I use alternatives lots but for various reasons would like to have a working 365.

Comment: Why do you have a personal email address that's the same as your work email address? This can sometimes cause complications, which is why you're recommended not to do that, and advised to rename your personal email address to something different. I'm only guessing but maybe this is the issue for the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to manually clean the MS Office activation and ID Keychain files in the "broken" MacOs user profile.

> Just after the step # .. : "And this: "Click Go>Go to folder>go to Library>Group containers>delete the folder UBF8T346G9.Office" (and deleted a few more folders besides)."

Follow these instructions:

1. **Quite** Keychain app, other apps and of course quite MS office app (including OneDrive, MS Teams, etc.).
2. Open the user's Keychains folder located in the user profile Library folder by using Finder (**Go** > **Go to** , or `command + shift + G`): `~/Library/Keychains`
3. Find and make a backup (Copy to some folder in Documents, etc.) any folders there which have UUID like names (a long alphanumeric string as a name, usually only one, for example: `550xxx00-exxb-4xx4-axx6-446xxxx440000`).

- Only these folders with their files. These folders are the Local Items keychain.

4. **Delete only** these folders you just saved in backup.

- **Don't delete** any files or other folders (usually - no folders) in the Keychains folder root (`~/Library/Keychains`)

5. **Reboot!**
6. Run the MS Office application (Word, MS Teams, etc.) and activate.

BTW Useful 3rd party utility to make 1st clean up steps:
https://office-reset.com/examples/

> This tool is independently published and has not been authorized, sponsored, or otherwise approved by Microsoft Corporation.